# jquery select every line that starts with &gt;

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the easist way to select every line that starts with the:

>

For example stackoverflow turns every line that starts with > into a quoted line. I want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex

```
stringVariable.replace(/(^>.+$)/gm,'<strong>$1</strong>');
```

example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/8yEBn/

Answer (score 0):

inputString.splitlines()
will return an array with all the lines in the input string

Then you are able to check wether line starts with > using:

```
 if ( line.match(/^>/) )
```

Untested, but should work.